# Need help in tuning a query in Oracle11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am modifying the original question as few conditions are changed -
I am running following query on Oracle11g & it takes 27 seconds to show the results. Can anyone please suggest the solution to improve the response time of the query? I am providing relevant details below -

```
select  Column1 , round(count(Column2)/10) 
from SE_CA 
where Column3 <= 4855 
and Column4 > 4490
group by Column1;

SE_CA table has total 123914265 records.

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3324421310

-------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name  | Cost (%CPU)|
-------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |       |   211K  (3)|
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY     |       |   211K  (3)|
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| SE_CA |   208K  (1)|
-------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("Column3"<=4855 AND "Column4">4490)



SQL> desc SE_CA;
Name                                      Null?     Type
Column1                                             VARCHAR2(3)
Column2                                             NUMBER
Column3                                             NUMBER
Column4                                             NUMBER
Column5                                             NUMBER
Column6                                             NUMBER
Column7                                             NUMBER
Column8                                             NUMBER
Column9                                             VARCHAR2(5)
Column10                                            VARCHAR2(12)


Index Definition -

CREATE  INDEX IDX1_SE_CA ON SE_CA(Column3);
CREATE  INDEX IDX2_SE_CA ON SE_CA(Column4);
CREATE  INDEX IDX4_SE_CA ON SE_CA(Column1);
```

- With both conditions applied, the expected output is around 10% of
  the entire table rows (10581643 rows).
- With each condition applied individually the output for column3 is
  10581643 and for Column4 is 12391426.
- Min & Max values for Column3 are 4623 & 4988 respectively.
- Whereas,Min & Max values for column4 are 4624 and 4991. respectively.

Can you please tell me if the index created are correct or do I need different indexes?

Answer (score 0):

The key to understanding whether you can improve performance on this query is to understand a couple of basic statistics on the data.

1. What is the range of values for the two columns that you have the predicates on (max, min)?
2. What percentage of the rows do you expect would meet each of the conditions individually?
3. What percentage of the rows do you expect would meet both of the conditions?

If the predicate Column3 <= 4855 is going to include 30% of the rows of the table, then a full table scan or fast full index scan would be the best choice for the optimiser, *if that is the only predicate on the table*.

Now, it could be that the predicate Column4 > 4490 s going to include 90% of the rows of the table -- based on that alone the optimiser might conclude that when the two predicates are both present then the proportion of rows to be retrieved is 0.3 * 0.9 = 27%. That still indicates that a full scan is appropriate.

However there could be a correlation between the two values, such that low values of column1 rarely have high values of column2, and only 3% of the rows meet that condition. In such a case it might be worth trying to use an index based access method.

This is a situation that optimizer dynamic sampling can detect by including the optimiser hint:

```
select /*+ dynamic_sampling(SE_CA 4) */  Column1 , ...
```

So get the answers to those questions about the distribution of values, and try dynamic sampling anyway -- this query looks like a good candidate for it, as I would imagine there to be a correlation between "EXPOSED_TIME" and "INFECTIOUS_TIME ;)

### Further

Since you are looking to retrieve about 10% of the rows from the table it is unlikely that an index-based method of accessing the table is going to help. Even an index range scan may be not be as efficient as the index fast full scan that the optimiser has chosen. It would depend on the efficiency of the i/o subsystem and the relative speeds of single and multiblock i/o. (Can you make sure that segment space is autoallocated or uniformly allocated in units of at least 1MB?)

However if you have the partitioning option available you could range-partition this table on EXPOSED_TIME in order to allow a more efficient partition pruning scan to select a subset of table rows. That's a big change to make, though, and a lot of care would have to be put into considering the side-effects on other operations.

You might also think about using a low degree of query parallelism, although again there are side-effects to this (a segment-level checkpoint, which could have a negative effect on a table with a lot of changes happening to it at the time).

Comment: Thanks David. I tried Dynamic sampling as you suggested but it didn't improve the response time. Let me provide you some more information you asked for - With both conditions applied, the expected output is around 10% of the entire table rows (10581643 rows) . With each condition applied individually the output is for column3 - 10581643 and for Column4 only - 12391426. Min & Max values for Column3 are 4623 & 4988 respectively.Whereas, Min & Max values for column4 are 4624 and 4991. respectively. Can you please tell me if the composite index created is correct or do I need different indexes?

Comment: Around 100 million rows for the entire table then? Which edition and version of Oracle are you on, and which options do you have licensed, if any?

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

Comment: And you're actually paying for enterprise and partitioning options, or are they just installed?

Comment: I am not the owner of the database server, so unfortunately I cannot get this information.